# Load selected options from cookie using jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, html-select

I store the previous submitted value in a cookie. Now on page ready I want to switch the selected form option to the value I stored in the cookie.

This is what I've done so far but it does not work. Any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Cookie data: testgroup,december
    var cookie      = $.cookie('billForm');
    var cookieArr   = cookie.split(',');
    var month       = cookieArr[1]; // holds december
    var group       = cookieArr[0]; // holds testgroup

    $('#groupsel select').val(group);

});
```

HTML

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    <select id="groupsel">
        <option>foogroup</option>
        <option>testgroup</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: did you check whether the proper values are retrieved by the cookie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
$('#groupsel').val(group);
```